# How to solve --ImageKit Error: error reading pixels: 506?

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard, ikimagebrowserview

My Cocoa (OS X) application is displaying Images in `IKImageBrowserView` on (Snow Leopard)10.6  but not displaying any Images (`IKImageBrowserView`) on (Lion)10.7.4 and throwing error on console

> --ImageKit Error: error before reading pixels: 506

and

> --ImageKit Error: error after reading pixels: 506

Is any changes require in `IKImageBrowserView` on 10.7.4 (Lion). Please help me to over come this problem. Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am displaying the images - the reason behind the "not displayed" images is improper Path but I am getting the same error in console...